# Are models always necessary to represent a particular db table?

Tags: python, database, model-view-controller, sqlalchemy

I have a database that is practically isomorphic to the model classes that it almost seems like a waste of time to create them. I'm using sqlalchemy core (not the orm), and I created gateway classes that look something like this example:

```
class BanGate(Gateway):

    def __init__(self):
            super(BanGate, self).__init__('ban')

    def ban_user(self, user, group, exp):
            data = dict(user_id=user, group_id=group, expires=exp)
            self._table.insert(values=data).execute()

    def unban_user(self, user, group):
            cond = and_(self._table.c.user_id == user, self._table.c.group_id == group)
            self._table.delete(whereclause=cond).execute()

class ForumGate(Gateway):

    def __init__(self):
            super(ForumGate, self).__init__('forum')

    def create_forum(self, group, user, title, desc):
            data = dict(group_id=group, creator=user, name=title, description=desc)
            self._table.insert(values=data).execute()

    def delete_forum(self, forum):
            stmt = (self._table.c.forum_id == forum)
            self._table.delete(whereclause=stmt).execute()
```

Creating a "ban" or "forum" class to hold on to state and save it using these gateways seems like a waste of time. For the controllers, I'm thinking about simply taking data from the request object and directly using these gateway objects, is this advisable? Most of the data for pages don't need to be manipulated, just saved and/or read, so the use of models classes don't seem necessary.

Also, the table classes used inside the gateways use the autoload feature, so I didn't define the database schema.

So basically how do I go about persisting data? Should I create a model class that gets passed into these gateway objects, or should I just simply pass the gateway objects data directly from the request objects?

(Also, by "gatway", I am referring to http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)

Comment: No. Actually, model is a layer and does not even have any single instance. Just like the other major layer in MVC design pattern - presentation layer - that contains controllers, views and other things. What you call "models" are actually [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) (or at least, i hope they are). And those too should not be tied to and single DB structure. Hell , they should not even be aware that DB exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in this case, you're reinventing an ORM by having to hand-code all those insert()/update() constructs etc, which is a lot more work than just using the persistence and querying facilities that are there.  If the "waste of time" is having the classes defined in code, there's no need for that if you want to use reflection, use a tool like [SQLSoup](http://readthedocs.org/docs/sqlsoup/) or just roll something similar, or perhaps [DeferredReflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeferredReflection).   In any ORM configuration, Python classes can be created on the fly using type(), so the ORM can be leveraged dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually am using reflection, the parent class 'Gateway' they both inherit takes the table name as an argument and uses reflection to load the table's schema. I thought the sqlalchemy core component was there for people who didn't want to use the orm; I like it when I create the queries myself and know exactly what they're doing. If this isn't a good way to use the sqlalchemy core component in a mvc way, can you please point me to a good example? Thanks

Comment: the core was designed for this use case, that's correct. But in practice, when you want to just create records and store/load them from the DB, the ORM is still a quick way to get that. The Core tends to be used for 1. if you really have a radically different approach to how your application does persistence (i.e. reddit) 2. if you want to emit very specific SQL in a specific way, typically for performance reasons 3. you are emitting some ad-hoc SQL that isn't part of a larger "persistence" pattern (like a data migration) 4.SQL-centric view of an existing database, not a lot of CRUD/repetition

Comment: Understood... One of my main reasons for not using the ORM was that I wanted full control of the queries and don't like the idea of a system generating them for me. Also, the data-mapper pattern implemented in the ORM seems overkill for this project, and I figured using a light-weight gateway pattern like above would be better (with that said, what do you think?). I will look over and reconsider using the ORM after reading your reply though. But, if I end up using this gateway approach, what do you think about simply passing data to the gateways directly from the request object?

Comment: (continued)... --that is, if creating an object for a particular entity (e.g. ban) would exhibit no behaviour like I mentioned above? Thanks

Comment: taking a dictionary from a request and sending it directly to a DB query is probably not how I'd do it, because in RL things never remain that simple.   The structure of the request and the schema of the database will invariably diverge so you might as well do some degree of explicit marshaling.

Comment: as far as "lightweight", that's an ambiguous term.  if it means, "uses fewer function calls internally", then yes the ORM is more heavyweight.  if it means, "need to write all this boilerplate configuration and verbose code", then the ORM is almost certainly  more lightweight, as its job is to automate data tracking, marshaling and CRUD generation.  As far as "generating queries", the ORM's query system is as explicit as that of the core on the SELECT side.  The lazy/eager loading features are optional. On the CRUD side, those queries are pretty redundant and un-controversial.